# Modify Timeout value in App Connect Enterprise

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

I am Making an HTTP Service with IBM ACE that has the following flow

[image]

The JavaCompute in this case called IndexHandler is doing a bit slow but necessary processing with the database and when I test it with postman I get an error "504 Gateway Time-out" when the process exceeds 30 seconds

[image]

Is it possible to modify the value of that timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything is configurable in ACE/IIB. Please see the [IBM docs for the HTTPInput node](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=nodes-httpinput-node)

I think you probably need to look at 'Maximum client wait time'.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the client wait time property from the HTTP Input node.

go to Error Handling Tab in Node Properties and Modify Maximum client wait time, default value is 180 Sec (3 Minutes)